# Parse JSON with German special characters

Tags: jquery, json, escaping, special-characters

I am trying to use $.parseJSON in jQuery to parse an translation file and get stuck in this line:

`"[„Alle“, „Spezifische Tage“]"`

which seems like parseJSON doesn't like the German Quotation `„ “`, I have tried to add either single or double backslashes but seems not working.

Is that anyway to modify the word `"[„Alle“, „Spezifische Tage“]"`, so it can be parsed into json, and still show the Quotation currently?

Comment: Still show the German looking quotes? You want the quotes to display?

Comment: yes. I still want the German Quotation shows correctly

Comment: Just to get this question clear... you have this string above... and you want this to be parsed as JSON including the german quotes so you get some like `„Alle“`and `„Spezifische Tage“` ? If yes, than I guess @JuanMendes is right with his answere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is not valid `JSON`, that is, you have unquoted strings. They must be quoted using `"` not `„` or `“`

If you want the German quotes to display, the simple solution for your data set would be for you to write some code to wrap your strings with regular quotes.

```js
var json = "[„Alle“, „Spezifische Tage“]".
    replace(/„/g, '"„').
    replace(/“/g, '“"');
alert( JSON.parse(json) );
```

The correct solution is for whoever generated your data to properly JSON encode it.

Answer (score 0):

Correct JSON format only allows double quotes:

```
JSON.parse('["Alle", "Spezifische Tage"]')
```

You can use http://jsonlint.com/ to validate your strings.

Comment: That's correct. The OP's string is not valid JSON. OP could use regular expressions to convert the German quotes into programming double quotes.

Comment: Actually this isnt an answere to the ops question. The german quotes are or should be a part of the string and not be replaced....